# Is there a way to specify QT5 printing settings on the command line?

Tags: printing, qt

I use Qutebrowser to "print" HTML pages to PDF. Everything works great if I click "properties," set the page size, and then set the margin, but I have to do this every time, and it's tedious. Is there any file where I can set these as defaults, so I won't have to do it each time?

I'm on NixOS. I don't have CUPS installed (and don't really see the point if I don't have a real printer), but I see that there are [several options in NixOS](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#cups) for printing. I also [opened an issue about this](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/4238) with Qutebrowser. Everyone seems to suggest configuring CUPS, but I don't know how to do that for printing to PDF.

[This bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65715?jql=text%20~%20margins%20and%20component%20%3D%20webengine) seems to say that it's the QPrinter module that applies the settings. Where can I find and change those settings? Is it something I can add to, e.g. [this cupsd.conf](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#cups)?

Comment: Hi Jon, Can you please add more details as to what platform you are on, Qutebrowser version and any config files you have looked on ?

Comment: Sure. Just did that.